# Spring Boot, returned view producing whitelable error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am unable to access the ListService.jsp page and print the data. Below is my controller. Please don't mind if this is a silly question. I have just started learning SpringBoot

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/users")
public class ServicesResource {

    @Autowired
    ServicesRepository servicesRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all")
    public ModelAndView getAll(ModelAndView view) {

            view.addObject("list", (List<Services>) servicesRepository.findAll());
            view.setViewName("ListService");

            return view;
    }
}
```

and the appilcation.properties file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.40.28:3306/ksrtc_oprsdb
spring.datasource.username=ksrtcdba
spring.datasource.password=ksrtcdba1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.hibernate.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

server.port=3001

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/Jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Below is my jsp file ListServices.jsp

```
<% Map x = (Map)request.getAttribute("list") %>
```

Comment: Your request attribute named `list` isn't a `Map` but a `List` hence casting will fail.

Comment: Actually i have written ${list}, but was still getting the same error.

Comment: Which error please add it to your question (or rather the stack trace on the server side of things). Also you are using Spring Boot so I would strongly suggest NOT to use JSP but something like Thymeleaf.

Comment: The error is Whilelable, 404 found, and there is not stack trace error. I am able get the data into the view. When the url is reloaded, this is what i am getting in the console. Hibernate: select services0_.SERVICE_ID as SERVICE_1_0_, services0_.SERVICE_NAME as SERVICE_2_0_, services0_.SERVICE_CODE as SERVICE_3_0_ from OPRS_SERVICE_MASTER services0_
2018-12-06 18:25:04.605  WARN 29298 --- [nio-3001-exec-4] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Path with "WEB-INF" or "META-INF": [WEB-INF/Jsp/ListService.jsp]